# Is is possible to schedule PyCharm index updates at night?

Tags: pycharm

It can start at any moment and may take more than 30 minutes, disalowing me to work. Of course, I can make coffee break, but not always.

Can this be disabled or planned to night?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is caused by either an incorrectly configured project or a broken plugin. Please contact the JetBrains support service and send your log and the contents of the .idea directory in your project, they will help you resolve this issue.